# Как правильнее организовать роутинг для данного приложения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, маршрутизация

Предположим, есть приложение, представляющее из себя сборник задач по различным языкам программирования и секторам разработки в целом (например, задания по верстке).

Нужно получить роутинг типа такого:
/ruby/tasks/strings/replace_a_with_b
/js/tasks/dom/get_element_by_tag_name
...и много других.

Мне НЕ нужно, что было так:
/sector/php/tasks/...
То есть я не хочу, чтобы перед языком еще писалось что-то типа sector, branch. Нужно, чтобы сразу можно было указать язык.

Сперва пришла в голову мысль использовать такое:

```
get ':branch/tasks/', to: 'tasks#index'
```

Но идея не подошла по причине того, что хочется использовать ассоциацию has_many - belongs_to (много заданий могут принадлежать одному сектору разработки, одной ветви), а в этом случае придется хранить ветвь, к которому относится данное задание в одной таблице с самим заданием, что не есть хорошо.

Потом подумал использовать scope или namespace, но я не думаю, что это самое рациональное решение. Тем более, что тогда мне тоже придется хранить все в одной таблице.

Позже решил использовать ресурсы:

```
resources :branch do
    resources :tasks
end
```

Но тогда получится полное неразбериха (1), я не думаю, что это рациональное решение (2), пути получатся не такие, как мне нужны (3) (/branches/3/tasks/25) и вместо названий заданий в адресе мне придется использовать их id (ровно как и id ветви разработки вместо ее названия).

Как наиболее правильно организовывается данная логика?

Comment: на самом деле, тут вопрос не как правильно, а как вам удобнее адресоваться к ресурсу, то есть исходит надо из того, какими бы вы хотели видеть пути к ресурсам

Comment: У вас очень странные умозаключения. Роутинг не связан с ассоциациями моделей **решительно никак**. Конвенции есть, но они не прибиты гвоздями. Роутинг влияет исключительно на то, в какой контроллер вы попадёте. Что вы будете делать в контроллере, это уже ваше дело.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Есть ли в Rails возможность использовать ресурсы с параметром, отличающимся от id?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545127/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-rails-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-i)