# Есть ли в Rails возможность использовать ресурсы с параметром, отличающимся от id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Например. Есть такой роут:

```
resources :cats
```

Он даст следующие пути:

```
/cats
/cats/:id
/cats/:id/edit
...
```

Есть ли возможность переопределить его так, чтобы вместо id он из БД должен был получать, например, его имя? То есть чтобы пути таких роутов:

```
resources :cats do
    resources :kittens
end
```

Выглядели примерно так:

```
/cats/:cat_name/kitten/:kitten_name
/cats/:cat_name/kitten/:kitten_name/edit
...
```

И еще смежный вопрос. Есть ли возможность создавать ресурсы без дополнительных слов в путях? Опять же, например, если есть такие роуты:

```
resources :cats do
    resources :kittens
end
```

То чтобы пути выглядели вот так:

```
/:cat_name/:kitten_name
/:cat_name/:kitten_name/edit
...
```

Или такие пути придется делать вручную get'ами, post'ами, patch'ами и delete'ами?

Рыл по этому поводу как Rails Guides, так и Rails Api. Вроде бы ничего дельного не нашел, но, вполне вероятно, что что-нибудь упустил или не так понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, разумеется. Надо только [знать нужные опции](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html):

```
resources :cats, param: 'name', path: ''
```

> `:path`
>   Allows you to change the path prefix for the resource.

`:param`, похоже, не задокументирован, но присутствует в константе `RESOURCE_OPTIONS`. Похоже, что он нормально себя ведёт только в условиях отсутствия вложенности ресурсов и наличии непустого префикса в `path` ([подробности в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/42538)).

Поэтому настолько гибкие маршруты (два `/сегмента` любого формата от корня), возможно, придётся бить на несколько частей с помощью ключа `:only`, внимательно следя за результатами и помня, что маршруты проверяются в порядке перечисления.

Comment: А что дает опция path? Почему вы оставили ее пустой?

Comment: > Allows you to change the path prefix for the resource.
Это и есть та часть перед параметром? Вроде /*cats*/:cat_id ?

Comment: @smellyshovel это очень просто проверяется. Оставляете в роутах только эту строчку и смотрите вывод `rake routes`.

Comment: Это я знаю. Просто хотел сначала все на словах уточнить. Сейчас проверю все это.

Comment: Весьма странный вывод получился: http://imgur.com/a/D4vag
Во-первых, теперь доступ к созданию новой категории не получить, потому как этот роут `/new` находится в самом низу. А во-вторых не понятно, почему в категории перед `hunt_name` есть префикс `:category`, а в посте просто `:hunt_name`

Comment: @smellyshovel то, что `/new` внизу, действительно странно. Из какого кода такое получилось?

Comment: Все в скриншотах по ссылке. В комментарий код просто если вставить, то он не мультистрочный будет.

Comment: @smellyshovel а, он ниже. Ага.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42538/discussion-between-smellyshovel-and-d-side).